# Can a Y/N prompt in the RStudio Console be deactivated?

Tags: r, console, prompt

I'm using a function from an R package called RAC (R Package for Aqua Culture). It generates a Y/N prompt in the console window prior to execution. Is there a way to deactivate the prompt or automatically answer N every time?

The function Bass_pop_main will generate: 
`Do you want to change the inputs? [y/n]`

Here's an example:

```
library(RAC)

setwd("../RAC_seabass") #working directory

userpath <- "../RAC_seabass" #userpath

Bass_pop_skeleton(userpath) #create input and output folders

forcings <- Bass_pop_dataloader(userpath) #load environmental variables

output <- Bass_pop_main("../RAC", forcings) #run growth model
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the post to include an example. The lines above the last line generates folders and csv files for the model to use (Bass_pop_skeleton), and then loads them (Bass_pop_dataloader).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any setting that you can supply externally which will allow you to answer "No" automatically every time. However, we can change the source code of `Bass_pop_main` according to our requirement and use it. The source code is available if you enter `Bass_pop_main` in the console.

```
library(RAC)

Bass_pop_main_revised <- function (userpath, forcings) {
   rm(list = ls())
   cat("Sea Bass population bioenergetic model\n")
   cat(" \n")
   currentpath = getwd()
   out_pre <- Bass_pop_pre(userpath, forcings)
   Param = out_pre[[1]]
   Tint = out_pre[[2]]
   Gint = out_pre[[3]]
   Food = out_pre[[4]]
   IC = out_pre[[5]]
   times = out_pre[[6]]
   Dates = out_pre[[7]]
   N = out_pre[[8]]
   CS = out_pre[[9]]
   out_RKsolver <- Bass_pop_loop(Param, Tint, Gint, Food, IC, times, N, userpath)
   out_post <- Bass_pop_post(userpath, out_RKsolver, times, Dates, N, CS)
   cat(" ")
   cat("End")
   return(out_post)
}
```

Now use `Bass_pop_main_revised` function instead of `Bass_pop_main` and it will never ask for input.

```
setwd("../RAC_seabass") 
userpath <- "../RAC_seabass" 
Bass_pop_skeleton(userpath) 
forcings <- Bass_pop_dataloader(userpath) 
output <- Bass_pop_main_revised("../RAC", forcings)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So I tried adding this updated function to the top of my R script but I get the following error: 

```Error in Bass_pop_pre(userpath, forcings) : 
  could not find function "Bass_pop_pre"```

For some reason R does not recognize these underlying functions when the revised function is in the R script. Was I supposed to save the revised function elsewhere?

Comment: @Zack it is not able to find function `Bass_pop_pre` which is different than `Bass_pop_main_revised`. Have you loaded `library(RAC)` at the top of the script?

Comment: I've confirmed that the RAC package is loaded. The other functions: Bass_pop_skeleton, Bass_pop_dataloader, and the original Bass_pop_main all work fine.

Comment: @Zack if you remove `Bass_pop_main_revised` function. Does it work?

Comment: I'm only able to run functions from the package. I've tried running an unaltered version of `Bass_pop_main` in addition to `Bass_pop_main_revised` as a code chunk at the top of my script with no luck with either.

Comment: @Zack Not clear to me then because the post isn't reproducible (so that I can test it on my system) but looking at the code I hoped this should have worked.